# Packet Sniffing and Sessions

Tags: c#, .net, session, packet, sniffer

Let us say that I have a website and that I created a session containing an encryption key.  Can a packet sniffer such as Fiddler be able to get the contents of this session, thus compromising the website's security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No because the key never goes through the network between server and browser. Session variables are stored in memory in the server machine. The attacker can only read the key if he gains access to the machine or if he can read from the machine's memory

Comment: Thanks :)  So storing a dynamically generated encryption key in a session is safe as long as only I have access to the application?

Comment: +1... also in non-development configuration session state likely to be stored outside of the process (i.e. in SQL).

Comment: @Matthew, Storing encryption key in session state is safe from being sniffed between server and client, it is up to you to decide if server-side locations are safe for your purposes.

Comment: @Matthew The key will not travel through the network so it is as safe as the server machine. To reduce the risk of an attack you should only keep it stored in memory while you need it.